# Excel VBA - Border issues converting to word

Tags: vba, excel

I am using userforms to transfer data into worksheet, then converting it to word document. I created bunch of tables to be fill in userform textboxes.  Since some of the comments could be very long, I set those tables as wrap text and autofit row height. While some of the tables are fitting word page, some of them are going beyond of page and some of the borders are going below page without proper format.[borders](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sUufd.png). 
I deleted contents in the word tables, you can consider it full of text.

How could I fit those borders into word document without overflow to the other pages?

```
Sub TestingMacAndWin1()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim appWD As Object
Dim wddoc As Object

On Error Resume Next
Set appWD = GetObject(, "Word.application")
If Err = 429 Then
    Set appWD = CreateObject("Word.application")
    Err.Clear
End If

Set wddoc = appWD.Documents.Add
appWD.Visible = True

With appWD.ActiveDocument.PageSetup
    .Orientation = 1
    .Content.Style = .Styles("No Spacing")
    .TopMargin = appWD.InchesToPoints(0.3)
    .BottomMargin = appWD.InchesToPoints(0.3)
    .LeftMargin = appWD.InchesToPoints(0.3)
    .RightMargin = appWD.InchesToPoints(0.3)
    .InsertBreak Type:=0

End With

Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B4").CurrentRegion.Copy
appWD.Selection.Paste



Sheets("C").Range("C6:F20").Copy
appWD.Selection.Paste

With appWD.Selection
    .Collapse Direction:=0
    .InsertBreak Type:=7
End With





For i = 1 To wddoc.Tables.Count - 1
wddoc.Tables(i).Select
wddoc.Tables(i).AutoFitBehavior wdAutoFitWindow
With wddoc.Tables(i).Range
.bordersall = True
.Font.Name = "Calibri"

End With
Next i



appWD.Activate

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: What's your question?

Answer (score 1):

Replace your `appWD.Selection.Paste` to `appWD.Selection.PasteExcelTable False, True, False`. It's work fine for me :

```
Sub TestingMacAndWin1()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim appWD As Object
Dim wddoc As Object

On Error Resume Next
Set appWD = GetObject(, "Word.application")
If Err = 429 Then
    Set appWD = CreateObject("Word.application")
    Err.Clear
End If

Set wddoc = appWD.Documents.Add
appWD.Visible = True

With appWD.ActiveDocument.PageSetup
    .Orientation = 1
    .Content.Style = .Styles("No Spacing")
    .TopMargin = appWD.InchesToPoints(0.3)
    .BottomMargin = appWD.InchesToPoints(0.3)
    .LeftMargin = appWD.InchesToPoints(0.3)
    .RightMargin = appWD.InchesToPoints(0.3)
    .InsertBreak Type:=0

End With



Sheets("Sheet1").Range("a1").CurrentRegion.Copy
appWD.Selection.PasteExcelTable False, True, False


Sheets("Sheet1").Range("b1:F20").Copy
appWD.Selection.PasteExcelTable False, True, False

End Sub
```

Before : 
[image]

After paste change :
[image]

Comment: No, it did not work out for me. Borders still going beyond the page.

Comment: What are those False, True, False stands for ?

Comment: @mesakon https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa220337(v=office.11).aspx

Comment: Could I disable "Automatically resize to fit contents option" in word from VBA? I think that would solve my problem.

Comment: I don't know because it's working for me. But try both 2 solutions : 1. add in appWD.ActiveDocument.PageSetup ".FitToPagesWide = 1" // or 2. disable all block "appWD.ActiveDocument.PageSetup" 
to see what happened

Comment: Some of the columns  in your after paste change picture, had been shrink ( cd,ced,ced,ced...) which I did not want it to happen.

Comment: All columns are auto adjusted by the text in the cells. It's hard to obtain exactly what you want without the same data.